# Array within an array using Facebook Graph APi

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, csv

I have been working on this problem for the last 2 days, searched over and over again .. nothing. Understanding that I am not an expert here - it's good! lol

I am trying to get the information found in the link below;

[https://graph.facebook.com/570215713050551_4508656/comments/?fields=likes.fields(id,username,name,profile_type)](https://graph.facebook.com/570215713050551_4508656/comments/?fields=likes.fields%28id,username,name,profile_type%29)

to then export into a csv.

Now I have current numerous other api tools, but this one has stumped me.

Basically, need to get the data foreach then run that again plus do the "next" paging etc.

Totally lost here.

My current code is here.

```
<?php
//Export and Download the Liker Data from each comment here .. 
$id = $_GET['data'];
$commentor = $_GET['commentor'];


$toget = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/comments/?fields=likes.fields(id,username,name,profile_type)';
$data = @file_get_contents($toget);


$data = json_decode($data,true);
if($data['data'] == FALSE){
    echo "gay!";
    die;
}

$alldata = array();

function moredata($data){
    global $alldata;
        foreach ($data["data"] as $eachdata){
            $onedata['id'] = $eachdata['id'];
                foreach ($eachdata["likes"] as $ex){
                $onedata['uid'] = $$ex['data'][0]['id'];
                $onedata['name'] = $ex['data'][0]['name'];
                $onedata['username'] = $ex['data'][0]['username'];
                $onedata['profile_type'] = $ex['data'][0]['profile_type'];
                //$onedata['link'] = $eachdata['link'];
                }
            $alldata[] = $onedata;
            $onedata = array();
        }

        if (array_key_exists('next', $data['paging'])) {
            $nextpagelink = $data['paging']['next'];
            $nextdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($nextpagelink),true);
            moredata($nextdata);
        }


}

moredata($data);
```

... ETC ETC to get out the csv

Any help here would be amazing! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was little tricky but can be solved the issue with nested recursion.

I have tried your code and made few changes and it worked. Check the code below

```
$alldata    = array();
$arrlikedata = array();

function moredata($data){
    global $alldata;
    global $arrlikedata;

    foreach ($data["data"] as $eachdata)
    {
        $onedata['id'] = $eachdata['id'];
        if(isset($eachdata["likes"])){
            $onedata['likes'] =  more_like_data($eachdata["likes"]);
        }
        else{
            $onedata['likes'] = array();
        }

        $alldata[] = $onedata;
        $arrlikedata = array();
    }

    if (array_key_exists('next', $data['paging'])) {
        $nextpagelink = $data['paging']['next'];
        $nextdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($nextpagelink),true);
        moredata($nextdata);
    }  
}

function more_like_data($likedata)
{   global $alldata;
    global $arrlikedata;

    if(isset($likedata["data"])){
        foreach ($likedata["data"] as $ex){
            if(isset($ex)){               
                $onedata1['uid'] = $ex['id'];
                $onedata1['name'] = $ex['name'];
                $onedata1['username'] = (isset($ex['username']))?$ex['username']:'';
                $onedata1['profile_type'] = $ex['profile_type'];                
                $arrlikedata[] = $onedata1;
                $onedata1 = array();
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($likedata['paging'])){
         if (array_key_exists('next', $likedata['paging'])) 
         {   
            $nextpagelink = $likedata['paging']['next'];
            $nextlikedata = json_decode(file_get_contents($nextpagelink),true);
            return  more_like_data($nextlikedata);  
         }
         else{
             return    $arrlikedata;  
         }
    }
    else{    
        return  $arrlikedata;
    }
}
moredata($data);

print "<pre>";
print_r($alldata);
print "</pre>";
```